# how to upload a GeoJson file to a db

Tags: javascript, geojson

I'm learning to program from a year old and I have a project in my hands, I created a map in Js and now I have a GeoJson file with the regions that I would like to upload to the map. Reading around I realized that I have to upload the file to a database and attach it to my index so that it works and I wondered how to do it? can anyone explain it to me? Thank you in advance...

Comment: Do you mean browser JavaScript or node.js application?

Comment: I don't know italian xd
If you want to use real database you have to use server side application which can access database. If you want to have those locations available only for one user you can store it in localStorage via JS.

Comment: Hi,no process JavaScript browser!